# It seems I haven't received some deserved badges!

Tags: support, badges

While going through the types of badges in SE, I came across these (in the picture) types of badges.
And then found that **I have a question with 10 points** and **Two answers with 25 and 40 points respectively**
But still haven't received any of the badges mentioned with these criteria.
Is there some technical issues or am I mistaken somewhere?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A score of 10 means "total upvotes minus total downvotes ≥ 10", not "earned you ≥ 10 reputation".

Comment: Thank you @orthocresol. I just mixed up between the 'scores' with 'reputation points'! =D

Comment: It can be confusing sometimes. Keep trying and you'll get the badge one day!